# How to write a special for loop case of C++ in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

Suppose this for loop in `C/C++`:

```
int start_value = 10;
int end_value = 20;
for(int i=start_value;i<end_value;i++)
  cout << i;
```

And if `start_value` is greater than `end_value` the loop will not iterate. How to write the same thing in `Python'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3.x

```
start_value = 10;
end_value = 20;
for i in range(start_value, end_value):
  print(i)
```

In python 2.x

```
start_value = 10;
end_value = 20;
for i in xrange(start_value, end_value):
  print i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function:

```
start_value = 10
end_value = 20
for i in range(start_value, end_value):
    print i # Or print(i) in Python 3
```

`range(10, 20)` returns:

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Note that if you're using python 3, `range()` will return an iterator (the output will still be the same however). This can also be achieved in python 2 by using [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange). It is mainly used for performance advantages.

In python, there is no need to do `i += 1` at the end of the loop because the for-loop automatically goes to the next item in the list after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> start_value = 10;
>>> end_value = 20;
>>> 
>>> for i in xrange(start_value, end_value):
...     print i,
... 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
>>> 
>>> start_value = 21;
>>> 
>>> for i in xrange(start_value, end_value):
...     print i,
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatically, the translation from C/C++ to Python 2 would follow correctly as:

```
start_value = 10
end_value = 20
for i in range(start_value, end_value):
    print i
```

Semantically though it's a little different than a C/C++ for loop. A Python `for` loop is what's generally known as a [for each](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) loop in programming.

> For each (or foreach) is a computer language idiom for traversing items in a collection.

These *collections* which support traversal in Python are called [iterables](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable).

> Unlike other for loop constructs, however, foreach loops usually maintain no explicit counter: they essentially say "do this to everything in this set", rather than "do this x times".

Your C/C++ code is an example of a [for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) loop in the proper sense.

> Unlike many other kinds of loops, such as the while loop, the for loop is often distinguished by an explicit loop counter.

So the `range` or `xrange` builtins can be used in a Python for loop to mimic the effect of a loop counter.

This would actually be closer to the semantics of the C/C++ example:

```
start_value = 10
end_value = 20
i = start_value
while i < end_value:
    print i
    i += 1
```

Translating something like `for (int i=1; stopCondition(i); i++)` to Python isn't as straight forward and would require an `if` statement and `break`.

This would be the semantics of the of the Python for loop example using `range`.

```
start_value = 10
end_value = 20
iterable = range(start_value, end_value)
iterator = iter(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        i = iterator.next()
        print i
    except StopIteration:
        break
```